# How to use Array key values to populate object data (Update Laravel db object)

Tags: php, laravel

I have an updated array of key-value pairs that i want to use to update a db object. Is there a way i can pass the string key as an object value?

```
$updated_data = array
            (
                "name" => "John S.",
                "email" => "john3434@mail.com",
                "note" => "Flight updated",

            );

$itemx = Flight::find($order_id);

foreach($updated_data as $key => $value)
{
    $itemx->$key = $value;
}

$itemx->save();
```

Comment: so u want update `Flight` with `id = $order_id` and data from `$updated_data`. why not just `$itemx->update($updated_data)`

Comment: Laravel will update your object when you put $updated_data in update function like you do with the foreach, but fields that not exits in the model will give error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$itemx->{$key} = $value;
```

But updating using `$itemx->update($updated_data)` like @Aslam proposes in the comment might be a better idea, although it does depend on the actual use case.